# HEALPix with texture UV mapping

Tags: uv-mapping

I found an implementation of the HEALpix algorithm [this is the dokumentation](https://healpix.jpl.nasa.gov/pdf/csub.pdf)
And the output looks very nice.

The following images show the latitude / longitude conversion to HEALpix areas.
The x-axe goes from 0 to 2 * pi. The y-axe goes from 0 to pi. The grey color represents the HEALpix pixel encoded in grey.

**Nside = 1**
[image]

**Nside = 2**
[image]

**Nside = 4**
[image]

**Nside = 8**
[image]

The different grey values are the IDs for the texture I have to use. That means, that each HEALpix pixel represents one texture. The missing part is the UV mapping within each of the HEALpix pixels like shown below:

**nSide = 1 with UV mapping**
[image]

Right now I am using the function:

```
void ang2pix_ring( const long nside, double theta, double phi, long *ipix)
```

Which gives me the correct texture ID. But I've no idea how to calculate the UV mapping for each HEALpix pixel.
Is there a way to calculate all four corners in lat/lon coordinates of a HEALpix pixel? Or even better a direct calculation to the UV coordinates?

BTW: I am using the RING scheme. But if the NESTED scheme is simpler to calculate I also would change to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research I came to a solution for this problem:

First of all, I've changed the scheme to NESTED. With the NESTED scheme and a very high nSide value (8192), the returned value from the

```
void ang2pix_ring( const long nside, double theta, double phi, long *ipix)
```

function gives back a long value where the UV coordinates can be read out in the following way:

Bit 26 till 30 represents the level 0 (only the 12 HEALPix pixels).

By using higher levels, the Bits from 30 till 26 - (level * 2) represents the HEALPix pixels.

The leftover 26 - (level * 2) - 1 till bit 1 encode the UV texture-coordinates in the following way:

Each second odd bit shrink together represents the U coordinate and the even once represents the V coordinate.
To normalize these UV-coordinates the responding shrinked values need to be divided by the value of pow(2, (26 - level * 2) / 2).

**Code says more than 1000 words:**

```
unsigned long ignoreEverySecondBit(unsigned long value, bool odd, unsigned int countBits)
{
    unsigned long result = 0;
    unsigned long mask = odd == true ? 0b1 : 0b10;
    countBits = countBits / 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < countBits; ++i)
    {
        if ((value & mask) != 0)
        {
            result += std::pow(2, i);
        }
        mask = mask << 2;
    }

    return result;
}


//calculate the HEALPix values:
latLonToHealPixNESTED(nSide, theta, phi, &pix);

result.level = level;
result.texture = pix >> (26 - level * 2);
result.u = static_cast<float>(ignoreEverySecondBit(pix, true, 26 - level * 2));
result.v = static_cast<float>(ignoreEverySecondBit(pix, false, 26 - level * 2));

result.u = result.u / pow(2, (26 - level * 2) / 2);
result.v = result.v / pow(2, (26 - level * 2) / 2);
```

And of cause a few images to show the results. The blue value represents the textureID, the red value represents the U-coordinate and the green value represents the V-coordinate:

**Level 0**
[image]

**Level 1**
[image]

**Level 2**
[image]

**Level 3**
[image]

**Level 4**
[image]

I hope this solution will help others too.